# how to exit from the server connection if not connected

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I have two servers and my client want to send same data to both server.but if server1 fails to connect client program waits and server2 is not getting data. I want to wait 1s for server1 if it fails to connect then server2 will get data.

```
import socket               
s1 = socket.socket()     
s2 = socket.socket()   
host1 = '192.168.0.3'
port1 = 12345
host2 = '192.168.0.5'
port2=12321               
s1.connect((host1, port1))
s1.send(data)
s2.connect((host2,port2))
s2.send(data)
s1.close()
s2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add try

```
try:
   s1.connect((host1, port1))
   s1.send(data)
except:
   print " s1 not connected"
try:
   s2.connect((host2,port2))
   s2.send(data)
except:
   print"s2 not connected"
s1.close()
s2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will automatically throws an exception if you are not able to connect to server you if you catch the exception the lines following will be executed.

for example:-
**client side**

```
import socket
import struct, time
import sys
# server
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 13

# reference time (in seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00)
TIME1970 = 2208988800L # 1970-01-01 00:00:00

# connect to server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
     s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except: # catch *all* exceptions
      e = sys.exc_info()[0]
      print(e)

try:
     s2.connect((HOST, 8037))
except: # catch *all* exceptions
      e = sys.exc_info()[0]



# read 4 bytes, and convert to time value
t = s2.recv(4)
t = struct.unpack("!I", t)[0]
t = int(t - TIME1970)

s.close()

# print results
print "server time is", time.ctime(t)
print "local clock is", int(time.time()) - t, "seconds off"
```

**Server Side**

```
import socket
import struct, time

# user-accessible port
PORT = 8037

# reference time
TIME1970 = 2208988800L

# establish server
service = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
service.bind(("", PORT))
service.listen(1)

print "listening on port", PORT

while 1:
    # serve forever
    channel, info = service.accept()
    print "connection from", info
    t = int(time.time()) + TIME1970
    t = struct.pack("!I", t)
    channel.send(t) # send timestamp
    channel.close() # disconnect
```

In the above client code one server port does not exit i.e localhost:13 so it will throw exception and i caught the exception and than the code following the erroneous code executed and hence connected to sever localhost:8037 and it returned the data.

Comment: sir i want to perform the rest program even if the server is faulty or not connected.or any other error occured. if i set timeout() it is showing timedout. or an error message is generating. kindly provide me one example